# Float div's to the right in left-to-right order?

Tags: html, css

I have multiple div's I want to display in a horizontal row. Normally, the way I'd do this is to simply float them to the right and put them in the markup in reverse order like so:

```
<div>
  <div style="float:right">Right</div>
  <div style="float:right">Middle</div>
  <div style="float:right">Left</div>
</div>
```

I'm trying to accomplish a similar thing, float div's to the right, but I can't reverse their order in the markup for SEO reasons. The left div needs to be first in the code.

Is there a simple way to do this without resorting to positioning things absolutely?

Comment: Any particular reason why you couldn't put them in order and then float them left?

Answer (score 88, accepted):

You could apply a `text-align: right` to the container and a `display: inline-block` in place of the floating:

```
<div style="text-align: right">
  <div style="display:inline-block">Left</div>
  <div style="display:inline-block">Middle</div>
  <div style="display:inline-block">Right</div>
</div>
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/didierg/r9n8h/)**

Comment: You beat me to it. I accomplished the same thing recently like this.

Comment: What does one do about the spaces that occasionally happen between the inline-block divs due to space characters in the HTML? Do you just jam the divs right together in the HTML with no space characters? Hard to read, if that is the case.

Comment: @FrankstonRalphingtonIII If you add some styles to the parent element you can get rid of those annoying spaces that break the document flow. Here's a link to some solutions: [link]http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/ [link]  My personal preference is the font-size:0 trick.

Answer (score 18):

Using `display:inline-block` might not work as expected with elements of variable height.

So you might want to use:

```
<div style="float: right">
      <div style="float:left">Left</div>
      <div style="float:left">Middle</div>
      <div style="float:left">Right</div>
</div>
```

See: [demo of both -- inline and float-float](http://jsfiddle.net/ze5x64e0/40/).

Answer (score 4):

You could give `float: right` to the outer div. And the display style of the inner div is `inline-block`

```
 <div style="float: right" >
      <div style="display:inline-block">Left</div>
      <div style="display:inline-block">Middle</div>
      <div style="display:inline-block">Right</div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score -8):

Float your elements to the left.

```
  <div>
    <div style="float: left; position: relative; width: 200px;">Left</div> <!-- dummy width -->
    <div style="float: left; position: relative; width: 200px;">Middle</div> <!-- dummy width -->
    <div style="float: left; position: relative; width: 200px;">Right</div> <!-- dummy width -->
  </div>
```

Also, you'll need to specify the `width` for each of these divs.

What is your reasoning behind floating them to the right?

Comment: @Jakobud: Bit late, but I would've thought that floating the container <div> to the right would do the trick.