# Span elements not lining up in expected order

Tags: css, html

I have 3 `<span>` elements inside of a div that are supposed to obviously line up according to their order. The last two items are supposed to be on the right. So I did a `float: right` but they are getting mixed up in the order. The "forward" should be on the right.

[image: screenshot]

**HTML**

```
<div class="caseTitle">
  <span class="caseNumber">Case</span>
  <span class="caseBack">Back</span>
  <span class="caseForward">Forward</span>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.caseTitle {
  background: #333;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 6px;
}
.caseNumber{}
.caseBack{
  float: right;
}
.caseForward{
  float: right;
}
```

Here is my fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/JGallardo/8wXNM/

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9280247/css-float-divs-to-the-right-in-left-to-right-order

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/TM382/

Comment: @furins that is not a duplicate at all.

Comment: if you apply the same approach proposed in the answer I mentioned, you'll get the result you expect. Just add a `caseNumber {float: left;}`. And it also explains how float  works. If you don't mind adding an additional div you may follow Travis answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can wrap the right floating items in a div and right float the div, rather than each word like so:

HTML

```
<div class="caseTitle">
    <span class="caseNumber">Case</span>
    <div class="wrap">
        <span class="caseBack">Back</span>
        <span class="caseForward">Forward</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.caseTitle {
  background: #333;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 6px;
}

.wrap{
  float: right;
}
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8wXNM/1/

Answer (score 0):

A quick and dirty way to fix this is to move the Forward div above the Back div.  Basically, the CSS is floating the first div it sees all the way to the right, and then the next div as far as it can.  So, if you move the Forward div in front, it will get floated before the Back div, which then is floated as far as it can.

```
<div class="caseTitle">
    <span class="caseNumber">Case</span>
    <span class="caseForward">Forward</span>
    <span class="caseBack">Back</span>
</div>
```

Instead of:

```
<div class="caseTitle">
    <span class="caseNumber">Case</span>
    <span class="caseBack">Back</span>
    <span class="caseForward">Forward</span>
</div>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uBdgs/4/)

Comment: not in this case, but this approach is not always preferable from a SEO perspective